# Strange error while building V8 in a Debian machine

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, makefile, v8, chromium

I am trying to build the [JavaScript V8 Engine](https://github.com/v8/v8) to explore it, debug it and have loads of fun.

However I am not being able to even compile it. I followed the following instructions:

**1)** Installing depot tools:

`cd ~`

`git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git`

`export PATH='pwd'/depot_tools:"$PATH"`

**2)** Compiling V8

`git clone https://github.com/v8/v8`

`cd v8`

`gclient config https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8`

`gclient sync` (I also tried `fetch v8` and it told me to run `gclient sync`)

`make ia32.debug`

And in this final instruction I get:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `third_party/icu/icu.gypi', needed by `out/Makefile.ia32.debug'.  Stop.
```

What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the instructions in the wiki, you don't "git clone https://github.com/v8/v8", you just "fetch v8" which is a depot_tools tool.

https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Using%20Git#how-to-start

Comment: (sigh), how does one do that if such a build platform is NOT on the network and is offline?